Dom text reinterpreted as HTML. Will it have any affect with input value
I am having the following
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      <input id="bc_hare_status_inp" value="<script>alert('hi')</script>" name="bc_hare_status_inp" />
    </form>

    <div style="margin-top:20px" id="hare_status">
      <select name="hare_status">
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

currently we have <script> code as value i.e $("#bc_hare_status_inp").val() .
Such things can happen, even though, this is a server rendered html, May be some <script> code got saved in their db and it now being used as a value
case1: the below does not have any affect but the codeql says Dom text reinterpreted as HTML. Because the script tag inside value of input cant run the script
    var caseStatus = $("#bc_hare_status_inp").val();
    rp_html = `<input type="text" value="${hareStatus}" style="width:250px">`
    $('select[name="hare_status"]').replaceWith(rp_html);

case2: the below runs the script and its agree to see Dom text reinterpreted as HTML
    var hareStatus = $("#bc_hare_status_inp").val();
    rp_html = `${hareStatus}`
    $('select[name="hare_status"]').replaceWith(rp_html);

should we take steps to overcome XSS attack even in case1, case2 is obvious

To avoid text interpreted as HTML use document.createTextNode():


var hareStatus = $("#bc_hare_status_inp").val();
const rp_html = document.createTextNode(hareStatus);
$('select[name="hare_status"]').replaceWith(rp_html);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="bc_hare_status_inp" value="<script>alert('hi')</script>" name="bc_hare_status_inp" />
</form>

<div style="margin-top:20px" id="hare_status">
  <select name="hare_status">
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
</div>




what about case1 <input type="text" value="${hareStatus}" style="width:250px">

@Santhosh if this rendered on server it should be sanitized with any html sanitize lib

ok. you mean like DOMpurify

@Santhosh why not
